# Create state transition diagram of a SSM that will output a "0" until the sequence 0, 1, 0 occurs.

Tags: digital-logic, state-machines

As the title states, I'm trying to draw the state transition diagram of a sequential state machine that will output a "0" until the sequence 0, 1, 0
occurs. After the sequence occurs, the machine should output a "1" regardless of the input.

Here is my work, but I've encountered a problem. What happens when we get to state S1, and the sequence adds a 0? If I send it back to S0, we can then have "010" going back to S1, which is valid and would output a 1. I only intended for the output to be 1 once I get to S3. How can I fix my diagram?

[image]

Comment: You need a self-transition on input `0` in `S1`. Otherwise the diagram is fine.

Comment: When it gets a 0 in state S1 it should go to S1. Also you forgot to indicate the initial state.